# Receiving inconsistent access violation working with queues

Tags: c++, dynamic, queue

I'm writing a simple queue program that runs through for loops and adds increasing values to the queue. After it reaches the capacity of the queue it creates a temporary queue that equals the new dynamically accolated queue and doubles the capacity of the new queue. It starts with a size of 8 but becomes an access violation when attempting the 124 array.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class queue {
public:
    queue();
    void enqueue(int item);
    void dequeue();
    int front();
    bool empty();
private:
    int * data;
    int myFront;
    int myBack;
    int size;
    int capacity;
};

queue::queue() {
    myFront = 0;
    myBack = 0;
    size = 0;
    capacity = 8;
    data = new int[capacity];
}

bool queue::empty() {
    return (size == 0);
}

void queue::enqueue(int item) {
    if (size == capacity - 1) {
        int * temp = new int[capacity * 2];
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            temp[i] = data[i];
        }
        delete[] data;
        data = temp;
        capacity = capacity * 2;
        myFront = data[0];
        //myBack = temp[capacity/2];
    }
    data[myBack] = item;
    myBack++;
    size++;
}

int queue::front() {
    return data[myFront];
}

void queue::dequeue() {
    myFront = (myFront + 1) % capacity;
    size = size - 1;
}

int main() {
    queue nq;
    // enqueue numbers 0-49
    for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
        nq.enqueue(i);
    }
    // dequeue 25 times. Show prints 0 1 2 ... 24
    for (int i = 0; i < 25; i++) {
        cout << nq.front() << " ";
        nq.dequeue();
    }
    cout << endl;
    cout << "Check point 1" << endl;
    // enqueue numbers 50-124. Now the queue should be 
    // 25 26 ... 124 from front to end
    for (int i = 50; i < 125; i++) {
        nq.enqueue(i);
    }
    // dequeue 100 times. should show 25 26 ... 124
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        cout << nq.front() << " ";
        nq.dequeue();
    }
    cout << endl;
    int temp1;
    cin >> temp1;
}
```

What part of the code creates this access error and what do I do to fix it? It runs seemingly fine for the first couple iterations but then stops accessing correctly towards the end.

Answer (score 0):

`enqueue` doesn't handle the queue wrapping, nor does the expansion properly handle a queue that has wrapped (where there is data at the end and beginning of the array with unused elements in the middle).

After you've removed the first 25 elements, the capacity is 64, elements [25..49] are occupied in the `data` array.  When you add the 15th new element (65), the size is only 39 so the queue storage doesn't expand and you write past the end of the allocated space.

`enqueue` needs to do the wrapping with `myBack` that `dequeue` does with `myFront`, and the expansion code needs to be changed to handle a wrapped queue.

Comment: Do I still need to wrap even though I'm dynamically allocating the array?